# send push notification in android from device to another

Tags: android, notifications, push

I am working on a cab booking  app . I am developping two applications the first one is B2C side (for the client who 's going to book a taxi) and B2U side (for the driver of the taxi).I need when a client make a reservation and the taxi driver accept it ,can both communicate with each other by sending notifications for example :the driver can send to the client  "i am about to arrive " etc and vice versa . I need a simple   way  to do this  apart of GCM because it's not totally free .I need an easy way without the need of developping a web service and make my own server .

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iapplize.gcmtest&hl=en

Comment: There's not really a good way to do this without some intermediary that both clients know to exist to help facilitate information exchange.

Comment: @Acco can you explain more ?

Comment: Think about it. Say you have a person (client) that wants pizza (business), but doesn't know any place that you could order pizza from. In this case, you'd be SOL without a phone book (server). After looking at the phonebook, said person now knows who to contact for pizza, and start communicating with the business.

Comment: Can i do this without using the GCM service , i just send the message to my own server and then it send it to the client ?

Comment: Not without having your client poll your server. Depending on how often you poll, you'll adversely affect the battery life of your client's device.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make your own server then go with socket programming. And implement your own push notification.But you don't have mention your server side platform so I am unable to provide exact implementation reference.

Comment: You could add a comment asking for more information related to the question, instead of writing an answer like this one.